# Two material themes in parallel

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

Is it possible to have two material design themes on the same app in parallel?

This is my use case:
Majority of the application has **mat-light-theme**, but I would like to have header and side nav to have **mat-dark-theme**, including all the components that sit inside them.

I can do this by manually overriding classes of course, but I am hoping for some more elegant solution.

This is what I tried (without success):

```
@include angular-material-theme($app-light-theme);

.drawer {
  // background: $primary-dark;
  // color: $cl-text-fg-dark;

  @include angular-material-theme($app-dark-theme);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was actually close to the solution, problem was that dark material theme was supposed to be defined on the **drawer-container** class, not **drawer**.
The same thing goes for the header - the dark theme has to be applied to a direct parent.

Hope this helps someone.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the [link to the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-material-themes) solution.

Comment: Can you share your code ? How do you use both themes at the same time ? What does it look like ?